# PHP FOREACH with 3 or more arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a panel that allows my admins to add posts. Not just one post, but multiple. They can click a button and it basically adds a few more input tags to add the name, link and description.

However, I'm having some issues with handling the `$_POST[]` values in PHP.

I'm doing something like so:

```
if(isset($_POST) === true){
    $pNames = $_POST["postName"];
    $pLinks = $_POST["postLink"];
    $pDescs = $_POST["postDesc"];
    foreach ($pNames as $pName) {
         foreach($epLinks as $pLink){
             foreach($pDescs as $pDesc){
                 // do stuff here
             }
         }
    }
}
```

My issue is that, it's basically doing it for each possible value. (Which as expected, I guess)

What would be the best way to get all of these to match up and work the way I want it?

For example, if I added two posts it'd be something like:

PostName1, PostLink1, PostDescription1

Then PostName2, PostLink2, and PostDescription2

and I'd want them all to be grouped together so I can add them into mySQL database accordingly.

Comment: You should be able to architect it so that you're able to do `for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['posts']); $i++) { ... }` and within the loop, use $i to reference each item i.e. `$_POSTS['posts'][$i]['name']`, `$_POSTS['posts'][$i]['link']`, etc. Using array notation for the form inputs will make this quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array notation for your form inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="post[0][postName]" />
<input type="text" name="post[0][postLink]" />
<input type="text" name="post[0][postDesc]" />
```

If you can rename the elements in this way then looping over the indexes would be the next best thing as others have described.

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that the size of all three arrays are always the same:

```
$size = count($pNames);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i){
    //do stuff here with $pNames[$i], $pLinks[$i], $pDescs[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys match up you can do something like this:

```
   foreach ($pNames as $key=>$pName) {
     $pLink = $pLinks[$key];
     $pDesc = $pDesc[$key];
     //do stuff here with $pName, $pLink, $pDesc
   }
```